# I can't see how log2 + log3 + log4 = log(n!)

Tags: math, big-o, recurrence

I can't see how log2 + log3 + log4 + ... + log n= log(n!)
The values work out, but I can't understand why they do.
Please help me out!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general mathematics.

Comment: This is better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/. And it is simply because of `log(a) + log(b) == log(a × b)`, which is one of the basic logarithm “laws” or [identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities).

Comment: well.. i asked a stupid question

Answer (score 12):

Because of the rule:

```
log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)
```